# how to convert filenames with special characters to valid filenames?

Tags: file, sharepoint, powershell, recursion, filenames

I would like to know whether it is possible to REMOVE special characters recursively in powershell from all files in an entire directory structure?

for example if I have a file called:

```
my presentation (fix).xlsx
```

I would like to rename it to:

```
my presentation fix.xlsx
```

thank you for your guidance.

the reason we need to do this is we are migrating many files into sharepoint 2010 and sharepoint doesnt like files with special characters!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't tested this code, but I think you probably want something similar to this:

```
Function Rename-Files($path)
{
 Get-ChildItem -path $path | 
 Foreach-Object { 
      $newName = $_.name -replace '[^A-Za-z0-9-_ \.\[\]]', ''
      if (-not ($_.name -eq $newname)){
        Rename-Item -Path $_.fullname -newname ($newName) 
      } 
 }
} #end function

Rename-Files -path "C:\somepath"
```

effectively, just loop through the directory *(modify the function to be recursive)* and then replace any inappropriate *(modify the regex for what is appropo)* characters and replace them with nothing *(effectively strip them out)*.

Comment: i am getting "source and destination files must be different!"

Comment: You probably don't want to run untested code. ;-)  Basically, the files that don't have any characters to strip out are not getting renamed, but it is trying to rename them to the same name. Just add a check to see if the $newName is different than $_.name

Comment: thank you so much can you please add that to the code (the check). very sorry my powershell is super weak

Comment: thank ou again for the change! i dont think this is currently working recursively, can you please update?

Comment: also how do you get the regex to ALLOW periods?

Comment: this is perfect! but how can i get it to be OK with periods?

Comment: Updated the answer with the regex to include periods.

Comment: yes absolutely! however this is not working with square brackets! can you please help?

Comment: actually there's a known issue about renaming files with BRACKETS so i had to run the solution below @zdan 's in addition to yours!

Answer (score 2):

The following command will recursively traverse your directory structure matching and for each file or directory that matches, performs a rename on that file by replacing each of the offending characters with an empty character using the powershell `-replace` operator.

Note that you will have to create a regular expression that matches all the regular characters that you wish to filter. To match the example you provide and remove round brackets, the regular expression would be:

```
$re = "[()]"
```

If you want to add square brackets, you have to escape them using backslashes:

```
$re = "[\[\]()]"
```

just keep adding characters between the outer square brackets as needed:

```
$re = "[\[\]()!]"
```

Here's the script, note the bit of dance so that the `-replace` operator only acts on the base part of the name at each iteration:

```
dir -Recurse | ?{$_.Name -match $re}  | %{ren -literalpath $_.FullName -newname (join-path (get-item $_.PSPArentPath) $($_.Name -replace $re,""))}
```

Some notes:

- The `-LiteralPath` argument on the `ren` command is required to be able to replace files with square brackets: [] it is only available in Powershell v3 IIRC.
- You may end up with name collisions after the rename, this script does not handle that.

Comment: Rename-Item : Source and destination path must be different.
At line:1 char:46
+ dir -Recurse | ?{$_.Name -match $re}  | %{ren <<<<  $_.FullName -newname (join-path (get-item $_.PSPArentPath) $($_.N
ame -replace $re,""))}
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\testing\2##!-_-:String) [Rename-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RenameItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand

Comment: Rename-Item : Source and destination path must be different.
At line:1 char:46
+ dir -Recurse | ?{$_.Name -match $re}  | %{ren <<<<  $_.FullName -newname (join-path (get-item $_.PSPArentPath) $($_.N
ame -replace $re,""))}
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\testing\Deme...nt Check Sheets:String) [Rename-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RenameItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов It seems like the `-replace` is not doing anything. I'll need to see the path and the regular expression you are using.

Comment: Awsome. Worked like a charm on folders and filenames. Thank you. Used `$re = "�"`  to remove the REPLACEMENT CHARACTER (U+FFFD �)

Answer (score 1):

May try experimenting with something like this:

```
gci * | % {$newname = $_.name -replace '\(|\)|{|}'  
           if (-not ($_.name -eq $newname)){
               rename-item $_.name $newname
           }
          }
```

Above would fix files like:

my presentation (fix).xlsx

test {ddd}.ps1

Comment: I can try...

$_.name is just a string. With -replace '{regex}', I am basically replacing the stuff I do not want with 'nothing'. In other words, I am taking the stuff out.

Regex part is separated by '|', which means 'or'. Because ( and ) are special chars in regex, I am escaping them with \.

if (-not ($_.name -eq $newname))
Now that I have the new name, by getting rid of special chars, I would like to compare that to what I started with. If the new name is different than old name, then I am renaming the old one with the new one. 

Hope this helps.

Comment: thats wonderful information thank you. how do you define SPECIAL CHARS? where in the code does it say to get rid of them?

Comment: Difficult to explain in this space but let me try:
1) Special Chars: $test= 'abcdef'. 
$test -replace 'abc(.)ef','$1' -> $test becomes 'd'. So everything inside paranthesis is captured as $1. Therefore '(' and ')' are doing something special; hence I called them special chars. If you learn about regex, you learn about them. 

2) Consider the following two uses of 'replace':
'someoldstring' -replace 'old','new' -> 'somenewstring' vs. 
'someoldstring' -replace 'old' -> 'somestring'