# how to convert function to work recursively

Tags: powershell

I have this awesome powershell script that will remove special characters from filenames:

```
Function Rename-Files($path)
{
 Get-ChildItem -path $path | 
 Foreach-Object { 
      $newName = $_.name -replace '[^A-Za-z0-9-_ ]', ''
      if (-not ($_.name -eq $newname)){
        Rename-Item -Path $_.fullname -newname ($newName) 
      } 
 }
} #end function

Rename-Files -path "C:\somepath"
```

i would like to know whether it is possible to get this working not just on the top directory but recursively through the **entire directory structure**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the `-Recurse` `Get-ChildItem` parameter. e.g.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path $path
```

Comment: thank you! this works. but how can i get it to also not touch periods, periods are valid!!

Comment: That's a problem with the regex character class you got from the [other question you asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798031/how-to-convert-filenames-with-special-characters-to-valid-filenames). Which you didn't list as a requirement btw.